# HTTP ERROR 405 running php from vs-code. I have 5500 port in my url

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

So recently I've been trying to create a sign up form-that actually works-for my website (which uses html, css, and js) and when ever I enter in some information and hit submit, I get redirected to an error page:
[image]

I use Opera GX as the web browser and I've also tried it with Google and it gives me the same result.

Here is my code that I used for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="form signup">
            <header>Sign Up</header>
            <form action="./register.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" required name="fullName"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" required name="email"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required name="password"/>
                <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="signupCheck" />
                <label for="signupCheck">I accept all terms & conditions</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='/pages/TodoList/todoList.html'"class="signup-btn">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $fullName = $_POST['fullName']
    $email = $_POST['email']
    $password = $_POST['password']

    // Database Connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'rtregister')
    if(conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connection Failed : '.$conn->connect_error)
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(fullName, email, password) values(?, ?, ?)")
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $fullName, $email, $password)
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        echo $execval;
        echo "registration Successful... Redirecting"
        $stmt->close()
        $conn->close()
    }
?>
```

Comment: 405 is the HTTP code for `Method not allowed`. i.e. it's telling you that `POST` is not allowed, taking what you have here at face value. You need to pull up the developer tools in your browser and find out exactly what method your browser is using and what the server is telling you in the response headers.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, however, for this register page, I need to use the POST method, but it doesn't support it in the response headers. Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: If the server is refusing to handle POST requests there's no work-around. You need to find out why the server is doing that, and change the configuration.

Comment: Just to be clear, you _do_ have a webserver with PHP integration running under port  5500 there, yes?

Comment: `<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='...` - that makes little sense, you either want to submit your form, or make a GET request for a different page. Both at the same time, will not work.